# Are there any programs out there that test the accuracy of OCR software?

Tags: software-testing, ocr

I am digitizing my old books and I was wondering if I needed to buy [OCR software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), or if the OCR software that came with my printer (Epson) would be sufficient. This made me wonder if there were any programs or software that tests the accuracy of OCR.

I imagine the way this would work is you would manually enter all the text in a paragraph, page, chapter, etc. Then, you scan the document with the OCR software and compare the results. I imagine it would give some figure such as a %. Alternatively, and potentially more exhaustively, though with a greater margin of error, you could upload an entire e-book to the program, then compare that with a complete OCR scan of the book.

None of my Google searches return any relevant results and, I lack the computer skills to create my own program, so I need one ready-to-use and relatively user friendly. Thanks for any help.